# What is 'v' key in bash vi-mode?

Tags: bash

While experimenting with bash vi mode (`set -o vi`) I accidentally pressed `v` while in normal/command mode then my editor(vim) fire up with a file named `bash-fc.XXXXXX`. what is this file? and why it opened upon pressing `v` key?

Comment: this open a visual editor that allow you to edit current command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>v</kbd> in Vi command line editing mode is the same as pressing <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> in Emacs command line editing mode.  It brings up the editor specified by `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` (or `emacs` if the environment variables `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` are unset) for you to edit the current command in a temporary file.  Save the file and exit the editor to execute the command.

From the `bash` manual (which does not document the Vi commands):

> `edit-and-execute-command` (`C-xC-e`)
>
> Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the
> result as shell commands.  Bash attempts to invoke `$VISUAL`,
> `$EDITOR`, and `emacs` as the editor, in that order.

Comment: Thanks for the info! so the `v` key was just the vi-mode keybinding for the `fc` builtin? I'm just wondering since I already had vim to display a custom statusline for `fc` (`FCEDIT= "$EDITOR -u ~/fcedit.vim"`) why it wont work for that?

Comment: @cevhyruz I'm not 100% certain, but there's no indication that `fc` is being invoked or that `FCEDIT` is being used when triggering this Readline library function.